# How to make collapse on clicking heading as well

Tags: bootstrap-modal

```
 <div class="box-header with-border">
  <h3 class="box-title">ADDRESS</h3>
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
```

how to make collapsible on clicking header div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its bootstarp collapse:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


<div class="container">
  <h2  href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <a href="#demo" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

hope it works

Comment: @munawar  it must have solved your problem!!!!give it a green tick at th3 left side and an upvote

Answer (score 0):

use

> data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#collapseExample" 
>   aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="box-header with-border">
  <h3 class="box-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">ADDRESS</h3>
    <div class="box-tools">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-box-tool" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> 
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```